# How do I replace a UIView with an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

In my program, I did something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJZ0PMulIgc) video and made my UIView draggable. I am making a Space Invaders type game where I would need that UIView to be the spaceship. It is currently just a normal UIView white rectangle. Is there a way to replace that white rectangle that is the UIView to an image? Or am I going at solving this the wrong way?

Comment: Use `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to replace that white rectangle that is the UIView to an image?

Sure, you can use a `UIImageView` in place of the `UIView` that you're currently using. Then you just configure the image view to display whatever image you want.

Another option is to create your own subclass of `UIView` that knows how to draw its content (a spaceship in this case).

> Or am I going at solving this the wrong way?

Games like the one you're building often draw the parts of the game using sprites, which are animatable sequences of 2D images. This is such a common thing that many platforms provide libraries that are dedicated to drawing and moving sprites efficiently. On iOS, that library is called [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/), and it's probably a better choice for what you're trying to do than trying to draw everything with views.

Likewise, there's a framework called [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/scenekit/) for working with 3D objects. That's probably more advanced than what you want, especially if you're just getting started.

Comment: If you are creating 'Space Invaders' type of game I would definitely take the time to learn and use SpriteKit.  That is what it was made for!:)

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to replace it, you can add a UIImageView to the UIView

```
UIView *view = your view;
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
[view addSubview:imageView];
```